# Mongoose query time increases exponentially when called consecutively

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose, nestjs, polling

I am working on a nestjs app and i am using a  mongoose find query in an api like this but when polled repeatedly the query time keeps increasing each time. like its in milliseconds for first few times then seconds and eventually goes to minutes and hangs my entire app.
but it only happens for pairs that has a large no of records. doesn't happen for smaller pairs.

I have tried applying indexes for `address` and `chainId` separately and combined but to no avail.
this is my query

```
const swaps = await this.PairSwapModel.find(
          {
            pairAddress: address.toLowerCase(),
            chainId
          },
          {
            hash: 1,
            amount0In: 1,
            amount0Out: 1,
            amount1In: 1,
            amount1Out: 1,
            amountUSD: 1,
            priceInToken0: 1,
            priceInToken1: 1,
            timestamp: 1,
            token0Address: 1,
            token1Address: 1,
          }
        ).sort({ timestamp: -1 })
```

Comment: What happens when you apply the query directly from the mongo CLI ?

Comment: Query runs fine from CLI. Plus i am querying the same collection from other places as well and they also run fine. Issue is produced in this particular case that too when polled repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Overall I think there is too little information here. If you provide the `.explain("executionStats")` output for a problematic version of the query then we would be able to assist more.

That said, the following sentence is probably important:

> I have tried applying indexes for `address` and `chainId` separately and combined but to no avail.

Based on the information in the question, there does not appear to be a field named "`address`" in your document. Rather, the field name seems to be `pairAddress`. We also don't know what the value of the `chainId` variable is from that snippet. If we assume that it is some equality filter on a field of the same name (e.g. `chainId: <value>`), then the following index should improve performance:

```
{ pairAddress: 1, chainId: 1, timestamp: -1 }
```